# How to add from ... to ... meta data to antd table pagination

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

here is sample image that is similar that I want to do

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#components-pagination-demo-total)? Antd's Pagination component is very similar to the table pagination.

Comment: Yeah but there is not anything that I want

Comment: The `showTotal` props is not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you opted for a custom solution when you can make use of the `showTotal` props:

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  pagination={{
    showTotal: (total, range) => `${range[0]} - ${range[1]} / ${total}`,
    pageSize: 10
  }}
  ...
/>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-header-antd4151-forked-79hvu?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution

```
const getTableMeta = (current, pageSize, total) => {
      let from = (current - 1) * pageSize + 1;
      let to = (current - 1) * pageSize + pageSize
    
      if (to > total) {
        to = total;
      }
    
      return (`${from} - ${to} / ${total}`)
    }
```

current, pageSize, total parameters can be taken easily using antd table pagination api.